# pandas выбрать топ 2 категории

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется датафрейм

```
data = {'фрукт': ['арбуз','арбуз','арбуз','груша', 'груша', 'вишня', 'абрикос', 'банан'],
'размер': ['1','2','3','5', '6', '10', '5', '7']
}
dates = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['фрукт','размер'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу выбрать записи о двух самых популярных фруктах?

Должен получить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dates.loc[dates.фрукт.isin(dates.фрукт.value_counts()[:2].index)]

    фрукт   размер
0   арбуз   1
1   арбуз   2
2   арбуз   3
3   груша   5
4   груша   6
```

Пояснение:

- Берём счётчик значений по колонке `фрукт`, используя `value_counts`
- Он отсортирован всегда от больших к меньшим, поэтому берём из него два верхних индекса (в которых и будут собственно фрукты)
- Выбираем из данных в таблице те строки, у которых значение колонки `фрукт` входит в отобранный нами ранее список наиболее часто встречающихся фруктов